# How do you represent a single inference rule (rather than a consequence relation) as a mathematical object?

Tags: logic

**How do you represent a single inference rule as a mathematical object?**

The most obvious ways I can think of are to make it a set of consequence relations, or to make it a sequence of symbols. I'll present the former below for concreteness.

---

The set of all inference rules can be represented as a consequence relation, which is a relation $\vdash \mathop: \mathrm{Set}[\mathrm{Wff}] \times \mathrm{Wff} \to 2$.

$\vdash$ is normally constrained in some way to satisfy some rules. For the definition below I cite *Algebraizable Logics* from Blok and Pigozzi.

$$ \varphi \; \text{is in}\; \Gamma \;\;\text{implies}\;\; \Gamma \vdash \varphi $$

$$ \Gamma \vdash \varphi \;\;\text{and}\;\; \Gamma \subset \Delta \;\;\text{implies}\;\; \Delta \vdash \varphi $$

$$ \Gamma \vdash \varphi \;\;\text{and it holds for every $\gamma$ in $\Gamma$ that}\; \Delta \vdash \gamma \;\;\text{implies}\;\; \Delta \vdash \varphi $$

$$ \Gamma \vdash \varphi \;\;\text{implies there exists a finite set $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ such that}\;\; \Gamma_0 \vdash \varphi $$

$$ \Gamma \vdash \varphi \;\;\text{and $\sigma$ is a substitution implies}\;\; \sigma(\Gamma) \vdash \sigma(\varphi) $$

However, $\vdash$ is a representation of *all the inference rules taken together as a single unit*, (with axioms being a degenerate type of inference rule).

A single inference rule is a slippery concept.

For example, here is *modus ponens*.

$$ \frac{\varphi \;\;\text{and}\;\; \varphi \to \psi}{\psi} $$

This definition is easy to *use* in a fixed deductive system, but is hard to study as a mathmetical object.

For example, the rule below is clearly a specialization of modus ponens.

$$ \frac{\varphi \land \chi \;\;\text{and}\;\; (\varphi \land \chi) \to \psi}{\psi} $$

The most obvious way I can think of to turn a single inference rule into an inspectable object is to make it a set of consequence relations.

Let $\mathrm{MP} = \{ (\vdash) : (\vdash) \;\text{is a consequence relation and $(\vdash)$ is consistent with} \; \mathrm{MP} \}$.

Let $\mathrm{WeakMP} = \{ (\vdash) : (\vdash) \;\text{is a consequence relation and $(\vdash)$ is consistent with weak modus ponens} \}$.

$\mathrm{WeakMP}$ is a superset of $\mathrm{MP}$ because it constrains the underlying consequence relation less.

In which case a deductive system specified by inference rules would just be the smallest (by $\subset$) consequence relation in intersection of the inference rules involved, if it exists and is unique.

This would make picking an axiomatization for a consequence relation  roughly analogous to picking a basis in other contexts.

Comment: I don't understand the issue here. What's wrong with just thinking of MP as $$\{((\varphi,\psi),\theta)\in\mathsf{Wff}^2\times\mathsf{Wff}: \psi=\varphi\rightarrow\theta\}$$ (where "$=$" is literal equality, not some sort of nuanced equivalence relation), or if you prefer $$\{((\varphi,\varphi\rightarrow\theta),\theta):\varphi,\theta\in\mathsf{Wff}\}$$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, hmm... I'm not sure, perhaps nothing. That might be general enough to capture all inference rules of interest. When I wrote this, I was also thinking about tableaux calculi which have rules that are kind of similar to inference rules in other calculi.

Comment: I cannot think of a single rule which is problematic to display in this way. If you can give an example that might help.

Comment: @NoahSchweber. The example I had in mind was the or-rule of the tableau calculus for classical logic, which splits $A \lor B$ into a branch for $A$ and a branch for $B$. This thing definitely constrains what the underlying consequence relation of the logic can do, but I don't think it can be represented in the manner above.

Comment: But the examples in your OP are about sequent calculus, not tableaux systems. (Part of the convenience of sequent calculus in my opinion is that it makes it very easy to talk about individual inference rules.)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when posing this question. I was messing around with a simple tableau calculus too shortly before writing this question and somehow came to the conclusion that inference rules were tricky. I think my question is just wrong.

Comment: See also the post [Symbols and notation in propositional logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464487/symbols-and-notation-in-propositional-logic)

Comment: No big difference with tableaux; see Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic (1968)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/First_Order_Logic/ZyLyCAAAQBAJ), page 20. The only trick is that tableaux rules work "in reverse" (from conclusion to premises) and thus the rules have only one "input" and one or two "outputs". Thus, instead of the usual form $⟨ \{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \},\beta ⟩$ they must be represented as $⟨ \alpha , \{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \} ⟩$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the premise of the question that "a single inference rule is a slippery concept." I don't see any issue with treating individual inference rules as straightforward relations on (tuples of) formulas. For example, to me **modus ponens** seems to be adequately understood as the relation $$\mathfrak{MP}:=\{((\varphi,\varphi\rightarrow\theta),\theta):\varphi,\theta\in\mathsf{Wff}\}\subseteq \mathsf{Wff}^{<\omega}\times\mathsf{Wff}$$ *(for simplicity I'm assuming here that we're only interested in finitary inference rules - of course this can be easily altered by modifying "$<\omega$" appropriately)*.

This is a perfectly well-defined mathematical object. So is the following "weak modus ponens" $$\mathfrak{WMP}:=\{((\varphi\wedge\psi,\varphi\wedge\psi\rightarrow\theta),\theta):\varphi,\psi,\theta\in\mathsf{Wff}\}\subseteq \mathsf{Wff}^{<\omega}\times\mathsf{Wff},$$ which is exactly the same as modus ponens but with the added restriction that the hypothesis must itself be a conjunction. Note that $\mathfrak{WMP}\subseteq\mathfrak{MP}$ in the usual set-theoretic sense, reflecting the fact that $\mathfrak{WMP}$ describes a "sub-rule" of $\mathfrak{MP}$. In general as far as I can tell all the "user-level" observations are straightforwardly reflected by "implementation-level" facts, as one would hope. And at no point do we even have to refer to consequence relations at all.